# Is it possible to use the 'instanceof' operator to identify the sub error types of built-in node.js errors?

Tags: node.js, inheritance, error-handling

Consider the following code executed in Node.js v 14.15.0

```
const assert = require('assert'); 
try {
  assert.strictEqual(true, false); 
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.constructor.name);           // Prints 'AssertionError' which makes sense as AssertionError is the name of the outmost class for this error and errors in Node 14 are more structured.  https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/errors.html#errors_class_assertionerror
  console.log(e instanceof Error);           // Prints 'true' which makes sense as the AssertionError class inherits from the base Error class.
  console.log(e instanceof AssertionError);  // Throws 'ReferenceError: AssertionError is not defined'
}
```

What is the correct way to reference the concept of `AssertionError` (and other Node built-in Error classes) so that they can be used with the `instanceof` operator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can assert specific error types

```
const assert = require('assert'); 

describe('test', () => {
    it('should catch error', () => {
        const assert = require('assert'); 
        try {
          assert.strictEqual(true, false);
        } catch (e) {
          expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(assert.AssertionError);
        }
    });
});
```

Using `instanceof` will also work (if not using assertion libs - e.g. using jest above)

Comment: How would one build the assertion for other types of built in errors? (e.g. `RangeError`, `ReferenceError`, `SyntaxError`, `SystemError`, `TypeError`, `RequestError` etc)

Comment: Check out the nodejs Error documentation https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_assertionerror
Errors which are extended from the Error class (to the best of my knowledge) are available globally.

Comment: `Errors which are extended from the Error class (to the best of my knowledge) are available globally.` This does not appear to be the case for `SystemError` or `RequestError`

Comment: Ok - I do believe that `SystemError` is a special case, that it is not exposed, so that is probably not able to be caught by type - however a list of the available system errors are available where you could check by code. There is no `RequestError` in Node. Are you referring to a `RequestError` from a lib perhaps?

Comment: My bad on `RequestError`. `SystemError` seems odd in the sense that `e.constructor.name` evaluates to `Error` when the error should be of type system error.